# Expanding CNN with GAN methodology in caffe

Tags: deep-learning, caffe

I have a network which estimates the `depth_map` from an input image. In a nutshell, I have an `input_image` and its corresponding `ground_truth` (depth map). Let us call this network a `generator` network. So far so good. Now I have heard of ´Generative Adversarial Networks`and I thought I could improve my network with adding a`Discriminator`-Network as follows:

```
input -> neural network -> estimated_depth_image -> discriminator -> output: true or false depending on real or synthesised 
                                                     ^
                                                     |
                                           ground_truth_depth_image
```

But then, how would I switch between feeding the estimated_depth_image with label 0 and feeding the ground_truth_image with label 1 into the discriminator. Is that even possible? If yes, how would you approach it?

My problem is, how do I feed my `new dataset` which is consists of all the groud_truth depth images with label 1 and all the estimated_deth_images with label 0 into the `discriminator` network at the same time using caffe?

Comment: I think you will find better answers on CrossValidated or Data Science. This question is a bit far from actual coding problems.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As far as I know this is not easy to do in Caffe, because you would need two different optimizers (one for the generator and one for the discriminator). You also need to do the forward pass only in G, and then in D using the output of G and some real depth data. I would recommend to use Tensorflow, torch or pytorch to do that.

Comment: Tensorflow, Torch or Pytorch is not an option. Why does one need two different optimizers? Does it even make sense what I am trying to do? I have read that GANs are actually for unsupervised learning rather for supervised learning like the task described above.

The only thing that is difficult or confuses me is the two different optimizers.

Comment: GANs are specifically two jointly trained networks. You feed back the loss of the discriminator as the negative loss to the generator (they are basically playing a minmax game). Otherwise the architecture is missing the point of GANs. I am not sure what you are trying to build, but it does not sound like a GAN.

Comment: In the end GANs are used if you want to generate output representing "realistic data"; they are not useful for optimizing supervised learning. So technically you have a distribution p represented by your training data and the goal of a GAN is to generate data q that is indistinguishable from p.

Comment: GANs can also be used in supervised tasks, one example is the  pix2pix paper. In that case, you would want to train the Generator not only with the adversarial loss but also with reconstruction loss (euclidean loss for example)

Comment: That is exactly what I want to do @RogerTrullo. I want to use the GAN with a supervised task. In this case I want to have a "reconstruction-generator" network with an EuclideanLoss where my input are images and ground_truth is the depth_map. And then I want to additionally use a "Discriminator" to improve my results. Do you think that is possible? Could you send a link t the pix2pix paper?

Comment: @MartinKrämer I think you are partially right, but what Roger Trullo said is what I want to do (comment above). Do you think sth like that could be possible? I would use my "reconstruction-generator" network twice. First I would run a normal iteration with EuclideanLoss and then I would use the Discriminator network two times, once for the depth_map_estimated and once for the ground_truth_depth_map. Do you think that might be possible? 
Have a look at this: [link](https://github.com/samson-wang/dcgan.caffe/blob/master/train.py)

Comment: I would use a similar code to the link above + an extra solve call at the beginning of the loop like: "reconstruction-generator".solve(1). So that first my network tries to reconstruct the depth map and then additionally I run the discriminator twice once for the reconstructed output and once for the ground_truth in order to increase my performance. What do you think about this @MartinKrämer

Comment: @thigi No idea actually. I never tried such an architecture. I would be interested myself to know whether this actually is better in the end than just optimizing reconstruction loss in a supervised fashion.

Comment: Yeah, this is exactly what I am curious about as well. I am sure it will take some time until I have some results, but if you want I could let you know as soon as I have some results. But I am not exactly sure, how to construct the architecture. Some people say caffe is not suitable for GANs but I think that link is proof that it should be possible. @MartinKrämer

Comment: I have one more question. Are you experienced with GANs. Is there anything to take into account when creating the "Discriminator" Network. Is there any relation between the "Generator" and the "Discriminator" architectural-wise? @MartinKrämer

Comment: I am only familiar with standard GAN arch, i.e. the Generator is a deconvolutional network that generates data from a noise distribution and the Discriminator is a convolutional network distinguishing between real and generated images, such that the Generator loss is the inverse of the Discriminator loss and training is a joint procedure. If training is not coupled I would not call it a GAN.

Comment: Yes it is absolutely possible, and it has been done. Here's the link of pix2pix paper (https://arxiv.org/abs/1611.07004), and here's another paper from my own work where we use similar ideas: https://arxiv.org/abs/1612.05362

Comment: @RogerTrullo You do exactly what I want to do as well in your paper. Do you have a github link for further details? How exactly does your training work? My training works as follows: I do one iteration for the "generator-estimation-network" and then I do two iterations for the discriminator network, first one is with the estimated output and second one with the ground truth. What are your learning rates for both networks? And what loss are you using for the discriminator?

Comment: Hello @RogerTrullo. I always switched to Tensorflow now from Caffe since Caffe is not very suitable for GANs. However, it is a bit hard to do the switch. I have created my network (Generator only) already and are able to train it. however, the testing step and the discriminator step are missing. Would you mind providing me some of your code to double check? Maybe just some parts? I do not need your model or anything, just the part where the generator and discriminator come together and how do you do testing whilst training?

Comment: HI thigi, here you can have atleast an idea https://github.com/rogertrullo/tensorflow_medical_images_segmentation
on how to do that, that was something I used before for segmentation but it is not finished, however, I think this link is better suited for your needs:
https://github.com/affinelayer/pix2pix-tensorflow/blob/master/pix2pix.py

Comment: Thank you. I am using the `stacked-hourglass´ network as a generator. Do you know anything about the correlation between generator and discriminator? Or what would kind of network would you use for the discriminator? Just some convolutions + batch? @RogerTrullo

Comment: `self.probs_G=tf.nn.softmax(self.G)` Didn't you say in your paper you are using `EuclideanLoss` for the generator? Why are you using softmax function here at the beginning for self.G? @RogerTrullo

Comment: That's why I told you, the work that I gave you the link is for segmentation. I still cannot share the code of the paper but it should be similar (instead of cross entropy use MSE, or L1 loss...

Comment: Okay, thank you! When do you think you can share the code? By MSE you mean this: `tf.reduce_mean(tf.square(logits - y))` because one can do the MSE in several different ways, but due the numerical problems for the computer I am not sure which one to use. @RogerTrullo